# How to remove intercept in R

Tags: r, intercept

I need to create a probit model without the intercept. So, how can I remove the intercept from a probit model in R?

Comment: Just add a `-1` in your formula as in: `glm(y ~ x1 + x2 - 1, family = binomial(link = "probit"), data = yourdata)` this will estimate a probit model without intercept.

Answer (score 52):

You don't say *how* you are intending to fit the probit model, but if it uses R's formula notation to describe the model then you can supply either `+ 0` or `- 1` as part of the formula to suppress the intercept:

```
mod <- foo(y ~ 0 + x1 + x2, data = bar)
```

or

```
mod <- foo(y ~ x1 + x2 - 1, data = bar)
```

(both using pseudo R code of course - substitute your modelling function and data/variables.)

If this is a model fitting by `glm()` then something like:

```
mod <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2 - 1, data = bar, family = binomial(link = "probit"))
```

should do it (again substituting in your data and variable names as appropriate.)

Comment: Is there a difference between using + 0 or -1 ?

Comment: @NiekdeKlein No, no difference that II am aware of

Answer (score 15):

Also, if you have an existing formula object, `foo`, you can remove the intercept with `update` like this:

```
foo <- y ~ x1 + x2
bar <- update(foo, ~ . -1)
# bar == y ~ x1 + x2 - 1
```