# R Remove intercepts in logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression, regularized

I am using the rms library to perform regularized logistic regression, and wish to force the intercept to zero. I'm using the following to simulate and regress:

```
library(rms)
N = 100
pred <- vapply(1:12, function(i) rnorm(N, mean = 0, sd =1), numeric(N))
resp <- 20*pred[, 1] - 3*pred[, 7] - 2*pred[, 8] + matrix(rnorm(N, sd = 0.1)) + 20
pr <- 1 / (1 + exp(-resp))
y <- rbinom(N, 1, pr)
lrm(y ~ pred, penalty = 1)
```

The post at [How to remove intercept in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216893/how-to-remove-intercept-in-r) suggests including '0 +' or '- 1' in the model formula. However, this does not appear to work for lrm.

Comment: do you have to use `rms` library?

Comment: Nope. I know of three possible libraries, `glmnet`, `LiblinearC`, and `rms`; if you know of any other, I wouldn't mind learning of them. I found `LiblinearC` ran longer and gave stranger results than `rms`; I'm testing `glmnet` right now.

Comment: I think glmnet is now the state of art.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Do you konw whether anyone has implemented the IRLS-LARS algorithm?

Comment: `glmnet` uses iterative coordinate decent which is also quite fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `glmnet`. It also includes a cross validation function for choosing the turning parameter.

```
library(glmnet)
N = 1000
pred <- vapply(1:12, function(i) rnorm(N, mean = 0, sd =1), numeric(N))
resp <- 20*pred[, 1] - 3*pred[, 7] - 2*pred[, 8] + matrix(rnorm(N, sd = 0.1)) + 20
pr <- 1 / (1 + exp(-resp))
y <- rbinom(N, 1, pr)
result <- cv.glmnet(pred, y, family="binomial", intercept=FALSE)
# best lambda based on cv
result$lambda.min
# coefficient
coef(result$glmnet.fit, s=result$lambda.min)
```