# how to generate a linear regression matrix like cor()

Tags: r, dataframe, linear-regression

I have a dataframe like below :

```
  a1 a2 a3 a4
1  3  3  5  5
2  4  3  5  5
3  5  4  6  5
4  6  5  7  3
```

I want to do linear regression for every two columns in the dataframe, and set `intercept` as 0.

In other words, I want to get the coefficients of `lm(a1~a2+0), lm(a1~a3+0), lm(a1~a4+0), lm(a2~a1+0), lm(a2~a3+0)...`

In `cor()`, if I input a dataframe, I will get a matrix back, e.g. below,

```
          a1        a2        a3        a4
a1 1.0000000 0.9467293 0.8944272 0.2045983
a2 0.9467293 1.0000000 0.9622504 0.4989222
a3 0.8944272 0.9622504 1.0000000 0.4574957
a4 0.2045983 0.4989222 0.4574957 1.0000000
```

In `lm()` is there any way to get the same kind of matrix?

Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry for my comment not related to your question but what that `+ 0` means? Are you trying to do not include an intercept in the model?

Comment: @SabDeM `+0` means removing the intercept.

Comment: I guessed so. I only knew to put a ` - 1` but now I know that  `+ 0` works well too as it is been said here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216893/how-to-remove-intercept-in-r.  Thank You.

Comment: @SabDeM Ah, I tried, also works....I don't know either....I'll check them, thanks~~

Comment: @SabDeM in `? formula` it says `It can also used to remove the intercept term: when fitting a linear model y ~ x - 1 specifies a line through the origin. A model with no intercept can be also specified as y ~ x + 0 or y ~ 0 + x.` So I think they are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a pretty general strategy

```
dd<-read.table(text="a1 a2 a3 a4
1  3  3  5  5
2  4  3  5  5
3  5  4  6  5
4  6  5  7  3", header=T)

mm<-diag(ncol(dd))
mm[lower.tri(mm)] <- combn(dd, 2, function(x) coef(lm(x[,2]~x[,1]+0)))
mm[upper.tri(mm)] <- rev(combn(dd[length(dd):1], 2, function(x) coef(lm(x[,2]~x[,1]+0))))
```

This gives the matrix

```
mm
#           [,1]     [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
# [1,] 1.0000000 1.202381 0.7738095 0.9285714
# [2,] 0.8255814 1.000000 0.6592593 0.7925926
# [3,] 1.2441860 1.508475 1.0000000 1.2033898
# [4,] 0.9069767 1.101695 0.7481481 1.0000000
```

where element [4,1] is the same as `coef(lm(a4~a1+0, dd))` and element [2,3] is the same as `coef(lm(a2~a3+0, dd))`

Comment: Thank you, it's really helpful. I want originally a single function though, but it work perfect~

Comment: While, just a comment, in the `upper.tri(mm)`, it seems simple `rev()` is not the right order to fill in the matrix. Maybe first `t(mm)` then `t(t(mm))` ?

Comment: I've also flipped the columns of `dd` now which I think fixes the problem.