# Trying to run regression analysis with multiple factors

Tags: r, glm

If I run `glm(company rank ~ sales + region, ...)` I get a rough set of company rank to sales. Company rank is a factor from A:D, so even when I try something like `multinom()`, I get factors B:D but not A. I understand A acts as the intercept but I'd like to get the individual values to every single sale in a region.

What would be the best way to go about getting every comparable value from A:D?

Comment: You may [cancel out the intercept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216893/how-to-remove-intercept-in-r) from the equation. But nothing really changes. The intercept gives the info about the factor A. And one more important thing. Other Factors (B:D) do not give you the individual effects , they are nothing but the "relative effects" wrt to factor A which is represented in the constant value.

Comment: is there a better method or package where I could get the individual effects of every variable without that being the case? @maydin

Comment: It is not a weakness, it is a necessity . You need to learn about "dummy trap". Just google it, you will get the point.