# lme4::lmer() With A -1?

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, random-effects

I am looking at an `lmer` model that's been coded, and I don't quite understand what the `-1` is / is doing. The code looks like `fit = lmer(resids ~ -1 + (1|loc/time))`

I believe the `(1|loc/time)`  piece can be equivalently written as `(1|loc) + (1|loc:time)`, which is a random intercept of `loc`, and a random intercept of `time` varying within `loc`.

Now the part I don't quite get: the `-1`, which I think has to do with the mean. The only place I have found that has anything on using a `-1` in that spot (as opposed to `1` or leaving it blank) is on page 7 of [Fitting Linear Mixed-Effects Models using lme4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf). The table here shows it in conjunction with `offset(o)`, which is used "*to specify that a random intercept has* a priori *known means*". So, my gut says that leaving the `offset(o)` out would be the same as using `offset(0)` (number `0` not character `o`), which would mean the *a priori* means are all `0`.

Is this correct?

Comment: It means suppress the intercept https://stackoverflow.com/a/14218910/5221626

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this sets the fixed-effect component of the model to exactly zero. While it is legal, this is a moderately strange model; I hope that whoever has coded it knows what they're doing. I can only think of two reasons you would fit a model with an empty fixed-effect component:

- for some reason you want to do a likelihood ratio test for the significance of the intercept (this is unusual, in most cases the intercept is not of particular statistical interest)
- you have a particular experimental design where the mean is known *a priori* to be zero (e.g. your response variable is some kind of difference between two elements that have been randomized to be exchangeable).

```r
lmer(Reaction ~ -1 + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
Formula: Reaction ~ -1 + (Days | Subject)
   Data: sleepstudy
      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
1840.7814 1853.5532 -916.3907 1832.7814       176 
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev. Corr
 Subject  (Intercept) 252.53       
          Days         11.93   0.88
 Residual              25.59       
Number of obs: 180, groups:  Subject, 18
No fixed effect coefficients
```

Comment: Point 2 is very common in social sciences and psychology.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it's an odd model.